# Update the top n rows of a table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
 year | value  | tercile
------+--------+---------
 1980 |   96.4 |
 1981 |    727 |
 1982 |  804.7 |
 1983 |    979 |
 1984 |    995 |
 1985 |  984.4 |
 1986 |  994.6 |
 1987 |  98.39 |
 1988 |     97 |
 1989 |  87.87 |
 1990 | 4054.3 |
 1991 |  82.89 |
 1992 |     94 |
 1993 |  97.61 |
 1994 |  99.68 |
 1995 |   99.9 |
 1996 |   9.42 |
 1997 |  75.66 |
 1998 |   2.16 |
 1999 |    696 |
 2000 |  99.38 |
 2001 |   9.81 |
 2002 |  99.27 |
 2003 |   2.75 |
 2004 |  12.51 |
 2005 |   9.29 |
 2006 | 994.71 |
 2007 |  97.06 |
 2008 |  64.44 |
 2009 |     95 |
 2010 |  40.88 |
 2011 |   9.46 |
 2012 | 742.86 |
 2013 |    9.5 |
 2014 | 736.38 |
 2015 |  93.13 |
```

I need to populate the 'tercile' column with values 1-3 according to the values in the 'value' column. 3 is assigned to the records with the 12 highest values, 2 is assigned to the records with the 12 middle values, and 1 is assigned to the records with the lowest 12 values.

I can retrieve these records with the following queries:

```
select * from trace_terciles order by value desc limit 12 
select * from trace_terciles order by value desc limit 12 offset 12
select * from trace_terciles order by value desc limit 12 offset 24
```

But I cannot figure out how to update the results of these `SELECT` statements. How can I do this? By using a subquery?

Comment: The best answer depends on a couple of things: Postgres version, exact table definition (PK, NOT NULL constraints?), actual number of rows. Do you want to assign rank numbers to all columns (1st, 2nd, 3rd third) or to 12 rows each, independent of the total number of rows? Is concurrent write access possible? Current answers are vulnerable to race conditions with concurrent write access. Compare: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
update trace_terciles set tercile=2 where year in (select year from trace_terciles order by value desc limit 12 offset 12)
```

and similarly for the other 2 cases.

Answer (score 2):

Update all rows in one query:

```
update trace_tercile t
set tercile = case
    when rank < 13 then 3
    when rank < 25 then 2
    else 1 end
from (
    select year, rank() over (order by value desc)
    from trace_tercile
    ) s
where s.year = t.year;
```